# Symfony 4 query elements from joined table if they exist

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine, symfony4

I have two tables gifts and gift_tags how can I select all gifts with tags that are not present in `$avoidTags` array only if gift has tags. The way my query works now it selects only the gifts that have at least one tag in gift_tags table and it is not in `$avoidTags` array, but I need also those that have no tags at all.

```php
$response = $qb
            ->select('g, tags')
            ->leftJoin('g.tags', 'tags')
            ->andwhere($qb->expr()->notin("tags.name", ":avoidTags"))
            ->setParameters(new ArrayCollection([
                new Parameter('avoidTags', $avoidTags),
            ]))
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the mysql, it can do with this query

```
SELECT 
  gift.*, tag.* 
FROM 
  gift 
LEFT JOIN tag ON gift.id = tag.gift_id
  WHERE gift.id NOT IN (
    SELECT g.id FROM gift AS g LEFT JOIN tag AS t ON g.id = t.gift_id WHERE t.name IN ('test', 'test2')
  )
```

So with the doctrine QB it maybe something like this

```
 $subQb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('gift.id')
            ->leftJoin('gift.tags', 'tags')
            ->where($qb->expr()->orX(
                $qb->expr()->in("tags.name", ":avoidTags")),
            ))
            ->getQuery();

$response = $qb
        ->select('g, tags')
        ->leftJoin('g.tags', 't')
        ->where($qb->expr()->notin("g.id", $subQb->getDql())))
        ->setParameters(new ArrayCollection([
            new Parameter('avoidTags', $avoidTags),
        ]))
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```

Comment: The thing is if a gift has 2 or more tags and one of it is from avoid list it anyway will print this gift because it finds other tags.

Comment: @serj I updated the answer, I tested the SQL query, but not the query builder

Comment: Except for some syntaxis problems with parentheses and unnecessary orX in the subquery, your answer solved my issue, thank you.